# updating the dataframe according to the specified conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(p = seq(1, 5, 0.5), s = 1:9)
b <- data.table(p = c(2.0, 6, 3.5), s = c(4, 7, 0))
```

I have 2 dataframes, dataframe "a" is the basis, dataframe "b" contains updates. I need to make changes to the dataframe "a" using the following conditions:

1. if in the dataframe "b" in the column "s" there is a value of 0, then it is necessary to remove from the dataframe "a" all rows with the corresponding value "p"
2. if in the dataframe "in" the value in the column "s" differs from the corresponding value "s" in the dataframe "a", then you must replace it with the value from the dataframe "b"
3. if the dataframe "b" has a unique value "p", then you need to add this line to the dataframe "a"

result:

```
     p s
1: 1.0 1
2: 1.5 2
3: 2.0 4
4: 2.5 4
5: 3.0 5
6: 4.0 7
7: 4.5 8
8: 5.0 9
9: 6.0 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr` (question does not specify if `data.table` syntax is necessary).

1. Get values for `p` that need to be deleted.
2. Filter out values found in 1. and use `distinct()` to make sure all rows are unique.

```r
library(dplyr)

to_delete <- 
  filter(b, s == 0) %>% 
  pull(p)

bind_rows(a, b) %>% 
  filter(!p %in% to_delete) %>% 
  distinct(p, .keep_all = TRUE)
#>      p s
#> 1: 1.0 1
#> 2: 1.5 2
#> 3: 2.0 3
#> 4: 2.5 4
#> 5: 3.0 5
#> 6: 4.0 7
#> 7: 4.5 8
#> 8: 5.0 9
#> 9: 6.0 7
```

Answer (score 3):

I first used full_join so that we have all the rows of both data frames. In case s.x and s.y are not equal and s.y is not an NA value it replaces s.x even in case of zeros which are later deleted. If s.x is NA and s.y is not which means that the row id for s.y coming from data frame b does not exist in data a it again replaces it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

a %>%
  full_join(b, by = "p") %>%
  mutate(s.x = ifelse(s.x != s.y & !is.na(s.y), s.y, s.x), 
         s.x = ifelse(is.na(s.x) & !is.na(s.y), s.y, s.x)) %>%
  select(-s.y) %>%
  filter(s.x != 0) %>%
  rename_with(~ str_remove(., ".x"), ends_with(".x"))

     p s
1: 1.0 1
2: 1.5 2
3: 2.0 4
4: 2.5 4
5: 3.0 5
6: 4.0 7
7: 4.5 8
8: 5.0 9
9: 6.0 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a join `on` 'p' (assuming they have the same precision of values) to update the 's' by the corresponding 's' from 'b' (`i.s`), remove the rows where 's' is 0 and `rbind` the rows of 'b' whose 'p' values are not in a's p

```
rbind(a[b,  s :=  i.s, on = .(p)][s != 0], b[!p %in% a$p])
```

-output

```
#    p s
#1: 1.0 1
#2: 1.5 2
#3: 2.0 4
#4: 2.5 4
#5: 3.0 5
#6: 4.0 7
#7: 4.5 8
#8: 5.0 9
#9: 6.0 7
```

Answer (score 1):

using `coalesce` it will be easier

```
a %>%
  full_join(b, by = "p") %>%
  transmute(p, s = coalesce(s.y, s.x)) %>%
  filter(s != 0)

     p s
1: 1.0 1
2: 1.5 2
3: 2.0 4
4: 2.5 4
5: 3.0 5
6: 4.0 7
7: 4.5 8
8: 5.0 9
9: 6.0 7
```